# bidimensional array C#

Tags: c#, arraylist, indexing

I want to have two arrays:

1. supplierList - that contains the int ID of each supplier element that i have in my graph 
   and then for each supplier that i have in this list a separate list
2. clientList - that contains the list of the clients of that determinate supplier.

so i want for example to have :

`[12,13,53,165,76]` that are the IDs of the suppliers and 
`supplierList[12]` the clientList of the supplier 12.

I tried with that:

```
    public void calculateMetrics (MDG graph)
    {
        ArrayList supplierList = new ArrayList();
        ArrayList clientList = new ArrayList();

        foreach (EA.Package package in modelRepository.Models)
        {
            foreach (EA.Package pack in package.Packages)
            {
                foreach (EA.Connector link in pack.Connectors)
                {
                    int supplier = link.SupplierID;
                    int client = link.ClientID;

                    for(int i=0; i<supplierList.Count; i++)
                    { 
                        if (supplier.Equals(supplierList[i]))
                        {
                            **((ArrayList)clientList((ArrayList)supplierList[i]).Add(client);**



                    supplierList.Add(clientList);
```

But without a surprise it doesn't work, but i don't know how to do it.

Comment: 4 levels of nested fors !! A definite candidate for refactoring. I apologize for the comment, nothing to do with your problem. Something that I observed.

Comment: Any reason why you're still using `ArrayList`, seven years after generic collections were introduced? If you're still using .NET 1.1, that could well change the answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can design it as following,

```
Class Supplier
{
    int supplierID;
    List<Client> clientListObj;
    //Additional Details
}

Class Client
{
    int clientID;
    //Additional details
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Why not create a Supplier Object that contains a List of Client IDs as a member variable?  This way you are only involving one List to iterate through directly and it will clean up your code.

More specifically:

Supplier object (Class) - Has ID (int), Client (Object)

Client object (Class) - Has ID, perhaps other properties.

Look up the syntax for object creation; you will find in an object-oriented environment, creating objects can really help out!

Comment: So i create a class Supplier that create the object that contains the list of clients? you mean like that?

Answer (score 0):

If you are familiar with dictionnaries, that what I would use. It would allow you to iterate through easy through suppliers or clients or a specific supliers client. To clean up your code, you could create a supplier class and a client class.

Here is a quick example

```
Dictionary<int, List<Client>> SuplierClients = new Dictionary<int, List<string>>();

        foreach (KeyValuePair<int, List<Client>> suplierClient in SuplierClients)
        {
            // your supplier id, could even replace it with a Supplier Object.
            Console.WriteLine(suplierClient.Key);
            Console.WriteLine(suplierClient.Value.ToString());
        }
```